# JMeter WebDriver Subsample labels not appearing in results

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

When using the WebDriver plugin for JMeter and using subsamples the labels that are set during the test do not appear in the results jtl file (and therefore the results tree/aggregate report etc.

WebDriver code (name = TestSampler):

```js
WDS.sampleResult.subSampleStart('First SubSample')
...
WDS.sampleResult.subSampleEnd(true)

WDS.sampleResult.subSampleStart('Second SubSample')
...
WDS.sampleResult.subSampleEnd(true)
```

**Desired outcome:**

result.jtl file:

...
1603546255925,1000,First SubSample,,,ThreadGroup 1-1,text,true,,0,0,1,1,null,0,0,0
1603546257658,1000,Second SubSample,,,ThreadGroup 1-1,text,true,,0,0,1,1,null,0,0,0

**Actual outcome:**

result.jtl file:

...
1603546255925,1000,TestSampler-0,,,ThreadGroup 1-1,text,true,,0,0,1,1,null,0,0,0
1603546257658,1000,TestSampler-1,,,ThreadGroup 1-1,text,true,,0,0,1,1,null,0,0,0

note that the only difference is that the value passed to the ...subSampleStart(label) function appears in the result file instead of an indexed version of the sampler name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   subresults.disable_renaming=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. Next time you will run your test you will see expected names

For GUI mode you can tick `Functional Test Mode` box on [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter Bug 62550 - Modify SubResult Naming Policy](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62550)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)